Conditional Probability of two time-series, where the follower one has an uniform distribution.
I'm trying to replicate the experiments of the paper: "On Consistency of Cross-Approximate Entropy in Cardiovascular and Artificial Environments", but I'm not sure if the true conditional probability calculation for Uniform is well coded. Could you help me?
For context, the paper is about the exploration of parameter space of the XApEn (Cross-Approximate Entropy). Fisrt, the authors carry a study over two artificial generated time-series with uniform and normal p.d.f.s (four experimental sets: both uni, both normal, uni-normal and normal-uni). The objective is to measure the relative error percentage between the true conditional probality ("p_im") and the estimated one ("p_im_hat").
However, using the equations of
Figure 1 and
Figure 2, the conditional probability equation obtained,
Figure 3, show the zero for values of x minus the threshold r outside the +-sqrt(3) interval, but the product if x-r is within it. Being the conditional probability related to the vector xm = {x(i),...,x(i+(m-1)}, with length m, an embedded vector of X, if at least one element of xm-r is outside +-sqrt(3), the result is immediately zero? That would be the same as having a zero element inside the product?
I'm trying to replicate the experiment in a MATLAB script, and the part related to this calculation of p_im is in the switch case 2:
        % True conditional probability, based on follower (y) pdf
        switch dataDist(2,1)
            case 0
                % There is not true conditional probability for biomedical data                    
            case 1
                % Normal
                for j = 1:m
                    p_im(i,1) = p_im(i,1) * 0.5 * (erf((xm(i,j) + r)/sqrt(2)) - erf((xm(i,j) - r)/sqrt(2)));
                end             
            case 2
                % Uniform
                for j = 1:m
                    if (abs(xm(i,j)) - r) < sqrt(3)
                        p_im(i,1) = p_im(i,1) * (min(sqrt(3),(xm(i,j) + r)) - max(-sqrt(3),(xm(i,j) - r)));
                    else
                        p_im(i,1) = p_im(i,1) * 0;
                    end
                end
                p_im(i,1) = p_im(i,1) / ((2*sqrt(3))^m);
            otherwise
        end

        % Relative conditional probability error [%]
        e_im(i,1) = (abs(p_im(i,1) - p_im_hat(i,1))/(p_im(i,1) + eps)) * 100;

Am I thinking right? In the case of X having normal distribution and Y uniform distribution, |x|-r could be greater than √3? If yes, I would get a division by zero, so am I missing something?
